# Find recipe by ingredient name, and sort if possiple

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have trouble writing queries for my database. I've found a number of similar examples here, and have been trying to get it around my head for hours, but none of the examples helped me figure out how to get the result i want. I'm building a recipe app but I'm really new to everything that concerns databases.
I would like to pick **1 or more** ingredients and get matching recipe **titles**, and if *possible*, sorted by best result (recipe which contains most ingredients). 
I've tried to make an inner join where I try to get recipe names together with matching ingredients.

And I've tried to do as this person does in this question because we have the same design: 
[Recipe Database, search by ingredient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427389/recipe-database-search-by-ingredient)

But even when i try to do the join as he/she does, just to test (and not as i would like it) it i get:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
```

Here are my tables:

Recipe_Ingredient

```
+-----------+---------------+
| recipe_id | ingredient_id |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 |             1 |
|         1 |             2 |
|         1 |             3 |
|         1 |             4 |
|         1 |             5 |
|         1 |             6 |
|         1 |             7 |   
|         2 |             1 |
|         2 |             8 |
|         2 |             9 |
|         2 |            10 |
|         2 |            11 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Recipe

```
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
|       id  | name                  | instructions |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
|         1 | Guacamole             | sample text  |
|         2 | Grilled avocado toast | sample text  |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

Ingredient

```
+------------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | avocado     |
|  2 | tomato      |
|  3 | chili       |
|  4 | garlic      |
|  5 | lemon       |
|  6 | salt        |
|  7 | black pepper|
|  8 | pesto       |
|  9 | spinach     |
| 10 | hard cheese |
| 11 | bread       |
+------------------+
```

sql

```
create table Recipe (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name CHAR(50),
prep_time CHAR(10),
instructions VARCHAR(2000));

create table Ingredient (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name CHAR(50));

create table Recipe_Ingredient (
recipe_id INT NOT NULL,
ingredient_id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(recipe_id) REFERENCES Recipe(id),
FOREIGN KEY(ingredient_id) REFERENCES Ingredient(id));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the things you have already tried. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @simbabque Thank's! Edited :)

Comment: Please, copy and paste your current query,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking query like this:

```
with cte as (
select recipe_id, count(*) as cnt from Recipe_Ingredient
group by recipe_id
) select r.id as Recipeid, r.name, c.cnt from Recipe r join cte c
    on r.id = c.recipe_id
    order by c.cnt desc
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! But how do i write if I want to search for avocado, and bread and get "Avocado toast" as first result because it contains most of the ingredients?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks!!