# SQL Search Recipe by Ingredient

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Database with Recipees and their Ingredients like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427389/recipe-database-search-by-ingredient)

Ingredients

```
+---------------+---------+
| ingredient_id | name    |
+---------------+---------+
|             1 | tomato  |
|             2 | onion   |
|             3 | rice    |
|             4 | chicken |
|             5 | beef    |
|             6 | noodles |
|             7 | salt    |
+---------------+---------+
```

Recipes

```
+-----------+------------------+
| recipe_id | name             |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 | tomato goodness  |
|         2 | meat deluxe      |
|         3 | chicken surprise |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Ingredient_Index

```
+-----------+---------------+
| recipe_id | ingredient_id |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 |             1 |
|         1 |             5 |
|         1 |             7 |
|         2 |             5 |
|         2 |             6 |
|         2 |             7 |
|         3 |             4 |
|         3 |             3 |
|         3 |             7 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

The code given in that Question does return more than I need so when searching for recipes with ingredients `1,2,3` I want only `Recipe1` returned and not also `Recipe2`

- `Recipe1       1,2,3`
- `Recipe2       1,2,3,4`

I am not that good with SQlite so what changes would I need to do so that it only returns Recipe1?

Comment: What is the logic for retaining one of these two recipes?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter in the `having` clause for all three . . . rather than in the `where`:

```
select r.name
from recipes r join
     ingredient_index i
     on i.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
group by r.name
having sum( ingredient_id in (1, 2, 3) ) = count(*) and
       count(*) = 3;
```

This returns only exact matches.  If you want *only* those ingredient, but not necessarily all three, then you can remove the second condition:

```
select r.name
from recipes r join
     ingredient_index i
     on i.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
group by r.name
having sum( ingredient_id in (1, 2, 3) ) = count(*);
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT r.name
FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN ingredient_index i ON i.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
GROUP BY r.name
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(i.ingredient_id ORDER BY i.ingredient_id) = '1,2,3'
```

If `ingredient_index` may contain duplicates (2 or more rows with the same ingredient for the same recipe - i.e. `ingredient_index (ingredient_index, ingredient_id)` is not defined as UNIQUE in the table DDL) then add `DISTINCT` to `GROUP_CONCAT`.

PS. The solution is MySQL-specific (the question is not DBMS-tagged but the thread which you are referring to is MySQL-tagged).