# Jetbrains Exposed SQL HAVING COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, kotlin, backend, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I need to achieve this next SQL query using the Exposed framework from Jetbrains

```
select r.name
    from recipes r
        inner join ingredient_index i on i.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
            where i.ingredient_id IN (7, 5)
                GROUP BY r.name
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This is taken directly from this answer, and the result from the query in native SQL is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm using Exposed framework on my backend.

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13427423/13150066)

I'm having issues with the last part `HAVING COUNT(*) = X`

I see there's a method I can use that's `query.having { }` but I don't see how I could implement the `COUNT(*) = X` inside that expression.

Any help is appreciated.